# Error: cannot read property 'controls' of null (formArray inside FormGroup inside FormArray inside FormGroup)

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray, formgroups

I have a form to add projects and repos for those projects. When adding a repo, you enter a POM URL. I am having trouble with accessing the POM URLs and it is preventing the form from loading.

I get the error "Cannot read property 'controls' of null

(The code is on another computer, so I'll recreate it the best I can)

**TS**

```typescript
this.addProject = new FormGroup({
  ...
  repos: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      ...
      pomUrls: new FormArray([new FormControl()])
    })
  ])
});

addRepo(): void {
  this.addRepos.push(new FormGroup({
    ...
    pomUrls: new FormArray([new FormControl()])
  }));
}

get addRepos(): FormArray {
  return this.addProject.get('repos') as FormArray;
}

get pomUrls() {
  return this.addRepos.get('pomUrls') as FormArray;
}

addPomUrls() {
  const control = new FormControl();
  this.pomUrls.push(control);

removePomUrl(index: number): void {
  this.pomUrls.removeAt(index);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<ng-container formArrayName="pomUrls">
  <div *ngFor="let _ of pomUrls.controls; index as i; count as c;">
    <las-ux-textfield [label]="'POM URLs'" [formControlName]="i"></las-ux-textfield>
    <div clss="button-container">
      <las-ux-button [id]="'addPom' + i" ... (click)="addPomUrls()"> </las-ux-button>
      <las-ux-button *ngIf="c > 1" [id]="'removePom' + i" ... (click)="removePomUrl(i)"> </las-ux-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

So as-is, this gives me the "cannot read property 'controls' of null" error

If I change get pomUrls to the following --

```typescript
get pomUrls() {
  return this.addRepos.at(0).get('pomUrls') as FormArray;
```

-- then it works perfectly...at least for retrieving at index 0. With this, I can add multiple pomUrls for a single repo, or add multiple repos with a single pomUrl.

**BUT** I can't add multiple repos with multiple pomUrls. Then it gives me an error "cannot find control with path: 'repos -> 1 -> pomUrls -> 1'". So it can't go beyond index 0, which makes sense.

My question is **WHY** I can't get this to work? Why does addRepos.at(0).get('pomUrls') work but addRepos.get('pomUrls') doesn't?

This is my first big project with Angular and I've been stuck on this for a week. I have been searching for help, wording this every way I can think of, and read through a lot of articles and other questions here on stackoverflow, but no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please add `?` to `pomUrls?.controls` in your template html.

`pomUrls` is undefined at some point in runtime.

`?.` is a null safety operator

Comment: This gets rid of the console error, but then the pomUrls textfield doesn't appear on the page. Any thoughts on why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

## About the problem

The easiest way to understand how this works is to visualize the value of the `FormGroup`

Below is how your `FormGroup` for `addProject` will look like

```json
  {
    repos: [
      {
         pomUrls: ['']
      }
    ]
  }
```

and this is for `addRepos`

```json
 [
   {
      pomUrls: ['']
   }
 ]
```

Now consider the below code

```
  return this.addRepos.at(0).get('pomUrls') as FormArray;
```

The above code takes the first item (`.at(0)`), and extracts the `pomUrls` property. Basically, if this was a simple JS code it would be `myFormGroup[0].pomUrls`. as you have mentioned this works perfectly.

Now lets try this code

```typescript
  addRepos.get('pomUrls')
```

Now the above is like trying to do the below

```js
  const addProject =   {
repos: [
  {
     pomUrls: ['']
  }
]
  }
  const addRepos = addProject.repos;
  console.log(addRepos.pomUrls)
```

So generally its like trying to extract a property from an array without getting a specific index first

## How to resolve?

You can use many ways to approach this. You can consider below

```typescript
getPomUrls(i) {
  return this.addRepos.controls[i].get('pomUrls') as FormArray;
}
```

In the above instead of setting `pomUrls` as a getter, use a function that takes in an argument of the index

**Edit 1**

Since we have removed `pomUrls` your `addPomUrls` will also have to change

```typescript
    addPomUrls(i) {
      const control = new FormControl();
      this.getPomUrls(i).push(control)
    }
```

Basically we are adding a pomUrls for a specific index of project

Comment: making the above change stops addPomUrls() from working (and a removePomUrl() I didn't include in the original question). It no longer works because property 'push' (and 'removeAt') don't exist on type '(i: any) => FormArray'. Would there be a different way to do my add and remove functions? *I added the remove function to my original question so you can see it too*

Comment: Thank you for adding in how to change addPomUrls accordingly. Unfortunately, now getPomUrls is triggering "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" error. I can't figure out why this.addRepos.controls[i] would be considered undefined?